# Which version of WebSphere is best for JSF2.0 web dev with PrimeFaces3.1

Tags: html, eclipse, jsf-2, primefaces, websphere

I am newbie with WebSphere. Recently I downloaded WebSphere Community Edition version 3 (WASCE v3) but there is no description about using WASCE v3 with JSF2.0 in the guide "Getting started with WASCE". I already build my web in Apache Tomcat 7.0.11 with JSF2.0 and PrimeFaces 3.1. I am using eclipse INDIGO. Now i have to shift my server to WebSphere. Please suggest me the best version of WebSphere, which is suitable for JSF2.0 with PrimeFaces3.1?
Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

WASCE 3 is a Java EE 6 container, so it has support for JSF 2.0 (if it wouldn't have this, it couldn't be called Java EE 6).

Do note that people typically don't mean WASCE when they refer to WebSphere. WASCE is another name for the server otherwise known as Apache Geronimo. The difference is that it's specifically supported by IBM.

What people do mean with WebSphere is the one you can find here: [ibm.com/software/webservers/appserv/was](http://ibm.com/software/webservers/appserv/was)

For JSF 2.0 you would need the latest version, which is version 8.

Comment: WASCE 3 is a Java EE 6 container, so it has support for JSF2.0.... For JSF 2.0 you would need the latest version, which is version 8.
I am getting some error with WebSphere Community Edition v3. This error might be because of no support for JSF2.0 with it (If it might support JSF2.0, IBM could provide some help in their ebook named "Getting started with WebSphere Community Edition"). Following is the error- 

    loader constraint violation: when resolving overridden method
    "org.apache.myfaces.taglib.core.SubviewTag.createVerbatimComponentFromB.......

Comment: You have the MyFaces JSF implementation on your classpath. Please remove it.

Comment: Hi dexter, I have  removed both JSF2.0 and JSTL1.2 from the build path. Eclipse smartly suggested me some new imports (like @ ManagedBean (name="login") is changed to @ managedBean (value="login")etc). However there are still some fields like FacesMessage (import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage) etc are highlighted as unknown fields. WebShpere must have their own implementation of JSF2.0 and JSTL1.2, but Eclipse is unable to guess them. I am totally confused now!!! My complete code was running perfectly with Tomcat, but here i even don't know the basic classes and imports. Help me please.

Comment: In order to let Eclipse know about the embedded classes in WebSphere, you must let it know you're using WehSphere. This happens via a `server runtime` that you download via the marketplace.

Comment: So what? i already installed the WebSphere v3 plugin by adding new software web-link to the "Install new software" option available under "Help" menu. What else should i need to do?

Comment: If you create a new dynamic web project, you can select a server runtime to base the project on. The libs published by that runtime will be put on the project's class path. Do note, again, that WebSphere v3 is NOT the same as WebSphere 8 and the server runtime is most likely completely different. For satisfying the compile dependencies any Java EE 6 runtime will do, but to actually start and stop your server from Eclipse you need the correct one.

Comment: Please check these screenshots. What is missing? What to do? 
(1)https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-BGzjECdFQxM/T1hp0WRPAQI/AAAAAAAACKE/A-LehBJOgq4/s304/Screenshot.png
(2)
https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-z9l1nFX504U/T1hqmn04mtI/AAAAAAAACKk/xzxVXfWAuOY/s712/Screenshot-1.png